# How to use the angular-eslint premade configs?

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint, angular-eslint

I'm replace tslint with eslint. After adopting the Anguar-eslint, I follow the readme to add some premade configs like below:

```
"overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

When run `ng lint`, only a few errors are found.
But if I add typescript-eslint recommended configs, thousands errors popup.

```
"extends": [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended"
],
```

Does this mean the `angular-eslint/recommended` does not include `typescript-eslint/recommended`?
Do I have to add both of them?
What about the `eslint:recommended`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this useful link
https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/issues/1174

```
As of v15, all new workspaces will extend from the eslint:recommended and plugin:@typescript-eslint:recommended configs
```